# Background check of international applicants

Tags: software-industry, resume, job-search, background-check, international

I am planning to apply for position of a Software developer in EU and New Zealand. I am from India and have been working with start-ups only. I have a total experience of 2.5 years, 1.5 years(Part-time), 8 months Full time with another company X and it's been 5 months at my current company Y.

I had a really horrible experience at company X and left at a really bad node. Now, since I am going to be directing a lot of time and energy in trying to find a position overseas, should I take off my  experience of 8 months from my CV? I don't want to do it since I was working on a really challenging project there on a real nice technology. But I am just SURE that if the company goes out for a background check, company X will try its best to ruin it for me (Totally!).

Would I be asked for any specific information before running any background checks? I don't even want company X to get to know anything about my interest in a position overseas.

In nut shell: I want to use the experience but don't  want a BG Check from company X.What is the best way out?

Note: . 
1. I don't have an experience letter from Company X. Can produce bank statements and confirmation letter though.

2. No payslips since they don't give it to anybody EVER no matter how many times you may ask. 
   (That may come as a surprise but startups do work that way sometimes).

Comment: Worry about the background checks only once you have an offer from a company. The people who do background checks are usually quite clever, and know who to speak to to get answers. They're interested in whether you have a criminal record and if you use drugs, but at the lowest level, that's about it.

Comment: @Pete I think India is a bit different from other countries. From what I understand, to leave a company in India you have to gain their permission to leave with a handwritten note. Basically you're owned by the company there.

Comment: @Dan not if you're going overseas, a company in NZ isn't going to care if you don't have a letter from your previous employer.

Comment: My comment about the OP worrying only when they have an offer is because they have little experience, and may have issues getting work permits, making everything else moot.

Comment: Thank you everyone. @Dan, That's correct. It's pretty much like that here. Also, why exactly was my question down-voted?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want a background check then don't mention it. But there is no guarantee that a background check won't find out anyway. It's best not to worry about these things too much unless you got fired for stealing or something serious like that.

Once you actually have a job offer the background check is mostly about criminal issues, the company has already invested quite a bit of time and money into you and minor things aren't going to be too much of a hindrance.

My personal experience with overseas people is I take all references good or bad with a large grain of salt. I'm more interested in their technical capability and criminal proclivities than anything else.

Comment: that's a criminal issue, whether rightly or wrongly, that's what it will appear as in a background check.